# javascript: setTimeout and clearTimeout issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to do polling via AJAX and want to clear the timeout after the AJAX call is successful. The problem is the timeout never clears and new AJAX requests keep on getting fired.

I looked up similar questions on SO, but they all suggest the problem to be a locally scoped variable. However, I am declaring the `poll_xhr` variable outside my function.

```js
<script>
var poll_xhr = null;
(function poll() {
    poll_xhr = setTimeout(function () {
     $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'check-status/',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                if(data === 'OK') {
                    clearTimeout(poll_xhr);
                    window.location.href = '../'
                }
            },
            complete: poll
        });
    }, 3000);
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Your program flow is: Set poll_xhr to a new timeout, it fires after 3000 milliseconds and starts an ajax request. On success you clear the timeout (not necessary, it has already fired!!) and on complete you poll again, starting a new timeout etc.

Comment: That's because AJAX request asynchronously calls `poll()` again on successfull callback. It simply fires the setTimeout again.

Comment: Can you post your `check-status` code here. I think `json_encode` not working

Comment: @Chinu check-status is working fine, I double-checked that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what your code does:

1. Start a timeout
2. When the timeout expires: Send an HTTP request
3. When the HTTP response arrives: Clear the timeout (too late, its already fired) and call `poll` which starts a new one.

Remove `complete: poll` and put `poll()` inside an `if` statement (where you currently have `clearTimeout`) if you want to make another request.

Comment: Got your point @Quentin, I want to do another ajax call if there's a failure / error, so should I put `poll()` in error attribute?

Comment: Your existing code implies that you want to make another request if the data isn't the string "OK". That suggests you want an `else` there and not an error handler. That said, your server side code might trigger an error, you haven't shared it with us.

Comment: my bad, I see how that can be implied. What I want to achieve if keep firing AJAX requests while there are 404 errors, and redirect to a new page when there's a success and data === 'OK'.

Comment: Then you do probably want to use an error handler for the repeat call then.

Answer (score -1):

In order to check, put some alert inside data==='OK'. if it doesn't came means, there is data type mismatch. To resolve this try with data=='OK'.